# Service IKEEXT automatically switched off after Windows 10 reboot

Tags: windows-10, services

After rebooting Windows 10, the IKEEXT service appears turned off - regardless of it previous state - started, stopped, automatically started or manually started. No problem to disable or enable it or run manually. Why the state of IKEEXT can appear switched off?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check the service dependencies: "Base Filtering Engine" and "Network Store Interface Service". Both should be set to Startup of Automatic, and both should be running.